# If $\frac{s_n -1}{s_n +1}$ converges to $0,$ then $s_n$ converges to $1?$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence, upper-lower-bounds

If $$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{s_n -1}{s_n +1}=0$$ then we need to prove:
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}s_n=1.$$

Here is my attempt:

If we express $s_n $ in terms of $t_n$ we've

$$s_n =\frac{-(1+t_n)}{t_n-1}.$$

How to proceed further?

Comment: What is  $S_n$? Is it $\sum_{k=1}^n s_k$?

Comment: @martycohen its just $s_n$. Typo sorry.

Comment: [Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35391) + [please avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933) + Hint: express $s_n$ in terms of $t_n:=\frac{s_n -1}{s_n +1}.$

Comment: @AnneBauval isn't it just the negative reciprocal of the given sequence?  I've did that and since the limit of given sequence is 0 the limit of $t_n$ becomes undefined. How can i go further with this?

Comment: @AnneBauval I've edited my question plz check

Comment: You could prove the contrapositive, that is, If $s_n\not\to 1,$ then $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{s_n -1}{s_n +1}\neq 0.$

Comment: $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{s_n}= 0$ where did you get this from?

Comment: I got it thanks for the help @AnneBauval

Comment: I invite you to edit a [self answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 2):

From $$s_n = \frac{-(1+t_n)}{(t_n-1)}$$

And $$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} t_n =0$$ we get $$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} s_n = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{-(1+t_n)}{(t_n-1)}= \frac{-1}{-1}=1$$